# Can I get a new token automatically when the old one expires Spotify?

Tags: javascript, spotify

The token in spotify expires at 1 hour. After an hour, you need to paste a new one. Is there a method to automatically retrieve a new token in place of the invalid?
Is there a way to automatically capture this token?
I would hold the token in the `token` variable.

```
return this. $ http.get ("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search", 
    {Header:{'Authorization': `$ {token}`}, params})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? You can refresh the token, store it, and use that for subsequent requests.

Comment: Every time I go to the spotify website - I generate a token on the page and paste it manually in the header in the $ http.get method in the headline. I do not want to paste this manually

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the authorization API?

Comment: Why I got minus vote ?

Comment: Because nobody knows what you're trying to do, in what environment, etc. Read the Spotify auth/auth docs.

Comment: After all, there is a javascript tag, in what environment can you do?

Comment: I've downvoted the question because they are too many ways to do what you want to do, and it is not clear how do you obtain the token in the first place.
There must always be a clear and definitive answer, not opinion-based.

Comment: You could be in the browser (React Native or regular browser) or server side. You could be authorizing an app or a user. You might want temporary or refreshable auth (sounds like refreshable). After all, the JS ecosystem is pretty big, and specifics actually matter. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of way to do that.

One of the way is to catch the rejection from the API (401 or 403 error), to generate a new token and to recall the first API.

Another way is to place a setTimeout to generate a new token after an hour.